# CSS - Change height of Storefront / WooCommerce product categories, but not products

Tags: posts, categories, pages, css, html

My homepage has both products and categories shown.
My shop page has only categories shown.

If I change the shop page category height, it changes the product heights also throughout.

I can set the category height on the homepage on its own, as I have placed these in a div and call it from CSS. However I cannot do this for the WooCommerce shop as they are thrown on the shop page automatically.

Here is the CSS I am trying to alter for the shop page only:

```
.page-id-6602 .storefront ul.products li.product,
.post-6602 .storefront ul.products li.product,
.page-id-6602 ul.products li.product,
.post-6602 ul.products li.product,
.page-id-6602 .site-main ul.products li.product
.post-6602 .site-main ul.products li.product {
    height: 275px !important;
    min-height: 275px;
    max-height: 275px;
}
```

but it's still grabbing this from my product heights throughout:

```
ul.products li.products {
height: 500px;
}
```

Any ideas?? Greatly appreciated.

website home page: [thailandpoolshop.com](http://thailandpoolshop.com)

website shop page: [thailandpoolshop.com/shop](http://thailandpoolshop.com/shop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thing you have .page-id-6602 .storefront on the body tag so you should be using selector like this
 .page-id-6602.storefront ul.products li.product

instead of 
.page-id-6602 .storefront ul.products li.product

also i am not able to access the shop page kindly check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this had no effect on the shop page.
The links at the bottom of the question should work fine. Just tested myself.

Comment: where do you get .post-6602?\